# how to keep alert dialog open if user not provide the whole information

Tags: java, android, xml

i have create a custom dialog where user will provide four information necessary from user , but if user click any button of alert dialog with out providing full information, the dialog is close, i want that alert not close unless the user provide full information 
this is Custom alert dialog
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aozjG.png)

```
this is java code for custom alert dialog



                final ExtraFunction ef = new ExtraFunction(mContext);
                final String PhoneNumber = holder.bdContactNumber.getText().toString();
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                View promptsView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_contact_for_blood, null);

                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                final EditText etSubject = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.etSubject);
                etSubject.setText(holder.bdBloodgroup.getText().toString());
                final EditText etNumber_Bottles = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.etNumber_Bottles);
                final EditText etRequired_At = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.etRequired_At);
                final EditText etContact_number = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.etContact_number);

                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(R.string.send_message, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // get user input and set it to result
                        // edit text
                        String Subject = etSubject.getText().toString();
                        String Number_Bottles = etNumber_Bottles.getText().toString();
                        String Required_At = etRequired_At.getText().toString();
                        String Contact_number = etContact_number.getText().toString();

                        String blood_message = ""+Subject+" Blood  "+Number_Bottles+" in Quantity is urgently required at "+Required_At+". Kindly contact at "+Contact_number+". Thanks.\n" + "("+R.string.app_name+")";

                       if(etNumber_Bottles.length()==0 && etRequired_At.length()==0 && etContact_number.length()==0)
                       {
                           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please Enter All Values....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           return;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           try {

                               SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                               smsManager.sendTextMessage(PhoneNumber, null, blood_message, null, null);
                               Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.success_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           } catch (Exception e) {
                               Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.failed_message + PhoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                       }


                        // ef.SendSmsFunction(PhoneNumber,blood_message);

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.Cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
```

i search but not clear about my problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086848/android-dont-dismiss-alertdialog-after-clicking-positivebutton

Comment: better use dialog fragment . for more guide use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did some wrong validation

```
 if(etNumber_Bottles.length()==0 && etRequired_At.length()==0 && etContact_number.length()==0)
                       {
                           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please Enter All Values....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           return;
                       }
```

---

as this validation works only when all the field empty instead of && operator you should use OR operator and take the string value of editText dont use length value direct on edit text first type cast to string than get the length. You can take use length method or equals method for this like below.

You can use this.

```
if(etNumber_Bottles.getText().toString().tolength()==0 || etRequired_At.getText().toString().length()==0 || etContact_number.getText().toString().length()==0)
                       {
                           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please Enter All Values....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           return;
                       }
```

Or by equals method:

```
if(etNumber_Bottles.getText().toString().equals("") || etRequired_At.getText().toString().equals("") || etContact_number.getText().toString().equals(""))
                       {
                           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please Enter All Values....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           return;
                       }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashrif Ahmad my 50% problem is solved but the main problem is to avoid custom alert dialog box closing , if i click any button (positive or negative) the dialog box will be close , only prevanting dialog box from closing is my problem

Comment: please vote for me if you got something valuable thanks @sifat uLLah shah. and please share your code for you dialog box close issue...

Comment: @Ashrif Ahmad i also have 6 reputation and cant be able to vote to any one ,

Answer (score 1):

`setOnShowListener` may solve your problem:

```
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Messsage")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
            .create();

    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() { 

        @Override
        public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button buttonOk = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            if (buttonOk != null) {
                buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Write what you want to do on button click
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Courtesy of [this](http:////http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked).

By the way, take a look on `EditText#setError` instead of yours `Toast.makeText`. Looks much more pretty!

P.P.S. I have changed my answer. You have to create AlertDialog and define `setOnShowListener` and your **dialog will not closed on the button click**. Is it what you desire?

Comment: Thank @isabsend but my point was that i want to validate Custom alert dialog box preventing closing if user not provide all the values , in activity it is easy but this is custom alert dialog box if i clicked any button (positive or negative) the dialog box will be close

Answer (score 0):

Bro you need to learn how to validate view look at this example -https://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/edittext-validation-in-android-example
and https://www.excella.com/insights/how-do-i-validate-an-android-form and https://stackoverflow.com/a/33072633/4741746

there are some library provide easy way of validation one you can prefer is https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar

**Best of luck**

Comment: Thank @sushan gosavi but my point was that i want to validate Custom alert dialog box preventing closing if user not provide all the values , in activity it is easy but this is custom alert dialog box if i clicked any button (positive or negative) the dialog box will be close