# Adding more than one Constraint

Tags: java, android

I have created a business upload form using android studio linked to firebase database, I am facing an issue where i could only add a constraint on the (name=empty display "please fill all fields"), but how can i add this to every other EditText field, so when the user does not fill them all the message shows.
here is the code

```
private void addBusiness(){

  String  name = businame.getText().toString().trim();
  String  email = busiemail.getText().toString().trim();
  String  number = businum.getText().toString().trim();
  String  address = busiadd.getText().toString().trim();
  String  info = busiinfo.getText().toString().trim();
  String  type = spinnerType.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
      String id= databaseBusiness.push().getKey();
      Business business = new Business(id, name, email, number, address, info, type);
      databaseBusiness.child(id).setValue(business);
      Toast.makeText(this,"Upload Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Fill All Fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `if ,else if` block

Comment: check below answer

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could look like this:

```
Map<String, String> userInputByTag = new HashMap<>();
userInputByTag.put("name", businame.getText().toString().trim());
userInputByTag.put("email", busiemail.getText().toString().trim());
...
```

And now you can **iterate** the map entries. If you find a map *value* that is empty, you can put up a message (using the corresponding map key). Not beautiful, but definitely better compared to

```
 if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
  ...
 else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
  ...
```

In other words: the straight forward but ugly solution would be a cascade of such if/else if/... statements.

Beyond that - I am pretty sure that Android has some framework support for field validation. You should do some research there, instead of re-inventing the wheel. Start reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072569/best-practice-input-validation-android) or [there](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html) or [that](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/109).

Comment: Thank you, i will do some research there.

Answer (score 1):

**Convenient for the user:**

I would use the more convenient way for the user and display beforehand an error directly in the EditText, if it is empty, with using a `TextWatcher` on every
`EditText`.

[TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

If you detect that the EditText is empty i.e. in `onTextChanged()`
you can call `editText.setError(yourString);`.

I recommend to use an `AppCompatEditText` with a surrounded `TextInputLayout`.

But nevertheless, before submitting, you have to do this for every member again.

Either you have a more user friendly approach with dedicated errors, like:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {

//dedicated error message
return;
}

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email )) {
//dedicated error message 
return;
}

//and so on

(...)
//if every field holds the correct information
databaseBusiness.child(id).setValue(business);
(...)
```

or you could just check for every member in one if statement and
display a generic error message like you already have.

Comment: Thank you, will do.